# Ruby on Rails: how to set content expiration for 15 minutes if it is an AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, browser-cache, cache-control

Is the following a good form of detecting AJAX request and setting expiration for 15 minutes so that the same GET will not require any network traffic?

```
# in controller
if request.xhr?
  response.headers['Expires'] = (Time.now + 15.minutes).httpdate
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = ''   # override any no-cache, must-revalidate
end
```

**Update:**  I found a shorter alternative, which is `expires_in`

```
# in controller
if request.xhr?
  expires_in(15.minutes)
end
```

although, after that, the header becomes:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=900, private
```

which used to be

```
Expires: Tue, 13 Jul 2010 00:59:47 GMT
```

when it was the earlier version.  But note that `Cache-Control` is for HTTP/1.1 and even a couple years ago, it was supported by 99% of the browsers, as mentioned in the High Performance Website book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since there is no answer yet, I am going to use the one in the update above:

```
if request.xhr?
  expires_in(15.minutes)
end
```

I tried it and it works well.